# laravel-elixir mix breaking jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, laravel-elixir

I am using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [laravel-elixir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir) package to combine and minimize my scripts and styles on a custom project.

Here is my current **guplfile.js** configuration

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.assetsPath = 'assets/';
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix
        .styles([
                'stylish_checkbox.css',
                'alertify.core.css',
                'alertify.bootstrap.css',
                'bootstrap-social.css',
                'intlTelInput.css',
                'slick.css',
                'style.css',
                'daterangepicker.css',
                'jquery.fileupload.css',
                'circle.css',
                'formValidation.min.css',
            ], 'assets/public/css/submit.min.css')
        .scripts([
                'jquery.js',
                'bootstrap.js',
                'jquery.tmpl.min.js',
                'alertify.js',
                'sisyphus.js',
                'slick.js',
                'formValidationFramwework.min.js',
                'formValidationBootstrap.min.js',
                'intlTelInput.js',
            ], 'assets/public/js/submit.min.js');       
});
```

My desired outcome is to combine all the styles in one file **submit.min.css** and all the scripts in one file **submit.min.js** and this works fine most of the time.

But now I'm getting these errors when I try to initialize jQuery plugins in my page: [image]

Any idea how to fix this?